# How to split a string (e.g. a long URL) in a table cell using CSS?

Tags: css, myspace, html-table

**Here's the situation**: I'm trying my hand at some MySpace page customisations. If you've [ever tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116610/myspace-dom) [stackoverflow], I'm sure you understand how frustrating it can be.
Basically it can be all customised via CSS, within a certain set of rules (e.g. the '#' character is not allowed...how useful!).
Have a look at this [blog](http://www.mikeindustries.com/blog/archive/2006/04/hacking-myspace-layouts) if you want more info, I used it as the basis for my customisations

So the only problem is with the comments section, where 'friends' post whatever they feel like.
It already has...

```
max-width:423px;
```

...set on the table, but I've discovered if long URLs are posted in the comment section, it blows out the table width, regardless of the max setting!

**Question**: Is there a way to manage text that is going to push the width of the table?
Perhaps splitting/chopping the string? Or is there more I should be doing..?
The URLs are posted as text, not hrefs.

Using Firefox and Firebug btw.

**Edit**: Also javascript is not allowed ;)

**Another edit** Just checked with IE7, and it seems to work.. so firefox is being the hassle in this case..

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the various values for the "overflow" css property?  I think that may do what you need in some permutation.

Answer (score 1):

a few browsers support [word-wrap](http://www.css3.info/preview/word-wrap/)

ex.

```
<div style="width: 50px; word-wrap: break-word">insertsuperlongwordhereplease</div>
```

browser support currently is IE / Safari / Firefox 3.1 (Alpha)

Answer (score 0):

Your options are pretty limited, if you are using only CSS. You can try

```
 overflow: hidden
```

to hide the offending parts. CSS 3 supports [text-wrap](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#wrapping), but support for it is probably non-existent. IIRC there is an IE-only css-property for doing the same thing, but I can't remember it at the moment and my Google-Fu fails me.