# html style not work in FF in MVC view

Tags: css

I have the following view:

```
<div style="width:600">
    <fieldset style="width:600">
    <table style="width:600" >
       <tr>
             <td>TEST</td>
             <td ><span class="displayData"><%= Html.Encode(Model.MyDESCRIPTION)%></span></td>  
             <td style="width:100%;" >&nbsp;</td>                  
             <td style="white-space: nowrap;">....</td>
             </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

I want to the width limited within 600px for printing, So I set the top `div` to `width=600`, wich works fine in IE, but doesn't work in Firefox.

For example, if the data for MyDESCRIPTION is something like:

```
12222222222222332222222132213123..123131111111111111111111111111111 
(no space, its total length will exceed 600).
```

In IE the line can be warpped to multiple lines within 600 limitation. But in Firefox, the line will be extended and there is no warp, so it will be cut by the display. But printing is fine for FF.

I'm very confused. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: You need to specify the measurement 'px' / 'pt' / '%' etc for your 'style' in the Fieldset & Table tags

Comment: even use style="width:600px;max-width:600px" for all, still get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You need the following CSS to force the line to break:

```
td span {
    width: 600px;
    white-space: pre-wrap; /* css-3 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */
    word-wrap: break-word; /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
```

Comment: The problem is: there is no white-space chars in this string. Even I apply the style above for the span inside the <td>, Still get the same result.

Comment: There are a few solutions in a previous question, though none seem to be perfect.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856307/wordwrap-a-very-long-string