# How to use automatic CSS hyphens with `word-break: break-all`?

Tags: css, word-break

I'm using `word-break: break-all;` and want to know how I can have the browser automatically insert the [hyphens](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/hyphens), as demonstrated in an [MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/cssref/hyphens.html).

```css
div {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
  word-break: break-all;
  hyphens: auto;
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
```

Such that the text would look like this:

```
aaaaaaaa-
aaaaaaaa-
aaaaaaaa-
aaaaaaaa
```

I created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LJYj3/2/) too.

This needs to work in IE9/IE10, but it'd be nice if it'd work in Firefox and Chrome as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `-ms-hyphens` property only works in IE10+. It's not possible in IE9 or below.

See the browser compatibility chart at the bottom of the reference link you provided.

It doesn't work in Chrome yet: [WebKit Hyphenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5356752/webkit-hyphenation)

Comment: As of 2015, the world isn't ready for css hypens yet: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-hyphens

Answer (score 30):

The `word-break` property and hyphenation are two completely different things. The first one, originally intended for East Asian languages mainly, does bad things to languages like English: it arbitr arily cuts w ords at some poi nts without ind icating that a word has been broke n.

So you should decide whether you have an expression where a line break can be inserted by a browser at any point or whether you want hyphenation.

For hyphenation, the CSS code as such is OK, though many people would advice putting the standard property setting `hyphens: auto` last, after prefixed properties. But it requires that the language of the text be declared in HTML markup, using e.g. `<div lang=en>`. Moreover, browser support is still limited: IE 9 does not support such hyphenation, and the support in IE 10 covers a relatively small set of languages (including English of course).

For automatic hyphenation on IE 9, you would need to use either server-side programmed hyphenation or, simpler, client-side hyphenation with tools like [Hyphenator.js](http://code.google.com/p/hyphenator/).

Answer (score 14):

Hyphens are inserted if the browser supports & language includes a hyphenation dictionary.
But your

`aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa`

isn't in a dictionary.

Therefore you have to insert soft hyphens `&shy;` to your satisfaction like in https://jsfiddle.net/LJYj3/5/

Here's more food for thought: https://stackoverflow.com/a/856322/1696030

Comment: Can you explain how that jsfiddle works? Where am I to insert the &shy; ?

Comment: @user1380540 You can insert a `&shy;` whereever you think it's appropriate to have a soft hyphen manual separation of a word.

Comment: Thanks for &shy;

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to find any css solution for this, so fix it with js.

```
const addWordBreaks = (str, maxLength = 10) => {
    const words = str.split(" ");
    const newWords = [];
    words.forEach(function(word) {
      if (word.length > maxLength) {
        const firstWord = word.substr(0,maxLength);
        const endWord = word.substr(maxLength, word.length-1);
        newWords.push(firstWord +"- \n");
        newWords.push(endWord)
      } else {
        newWords.push(word)
      }
    });
     return newWords.join(" ");
  }
```