# How to auto-line-break heading?

Tags: html, css

Take this code for example

```css
.test {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1 class="test">This is a Headindfdfdfdfdsdfsdffdfdfdfddfdfdfddfghfghfddfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdffdffdfdffdg</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

I restrict the width of the heading to be half of the whole page, and I wish the text could automatically line breaking once it reaches out of the margin. But it doesn't work.

So, how to automatically (not using `</br>`) line breaking a heading ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the rule [`word-break:break-word;`](http://%20%20word-break:break-word;)

```css
.test {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  word-break:break-word;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>

  <h1 class="test">This is a Headindfdfdfdfdsdfsdffdfdfdfddfdfdfddfghfghfddfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdffdffdfdffdg</h1>

</body>

</html>
```

Note that there's also [`overflow-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap) which can be used.

Comment: Thank you. But how do you know about this? I tried to google `html heading line break` but got nothing useful.

Comment: @NathanExplosion 20+ years of experience ;)

Comment: But actually, I find that the line break for a word does not give you a hyphen. How to enable a hyphen?

Comment: @NathanExplosion That's a different question and for that, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261605/how-to-use-automatic-css-hyphens-with-word-break-break-all

Answer (score 0):

use css word-wrap

```css
.test {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="test">This is a Headindfdfdfdfdsdfsdffdfdfdfddfdfdfddfghfghfddfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdffdffdfdffdg</h1>
```

Comment: `word-wrap` is now `overflow-wrap`