# text does not wrap if has no commas , dots , \n 

Tags: html, css

I have a long text to put in a DIV , it does not wrap and all of the text is displayed in one line .

tried every CSS i know from `word-wrap` to `white-space` but nothing works .

if the text contained a `\n` or `,` or `.` it wraps .

Any idea on how to wrap it even if none of these existed ? without using the `width` in css

Thank you .

Comment: possible duplicate of [wordwrap a very long string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856307/wordwrap-a-very-long-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previously answered:

[wordwrap a very long string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856307/wordwrap-a-very-long-string)

Comment: Though it didn't work without adding a `width` in the css , but i managed to add it .

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to this is the css property `word-wrap: break-word`.

See [wordwrap a very long string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856307/wordwrap-a-very-long-string) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
white-space: normal;
word-wrap: break-word;
```