# Breaking words using CSS

Tags: html, css, word-break

[image: screenshot]

When the text in `<p>` tag is too long, it appears like this, how to prevent this with CSS? I've tried the CSS property `word-break: break-all;` but Firefox and Opera doesn't support this property, and besides that other "normal" words also breaking. So I want to break only very long words, but not short words, depending on width of white `<div>`.

```css
body {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
h2 {
    float: left;
    color: #525254;
    margin: 0px;
    font: bold 15px Arial, Helvetica, sans;
}
.post {
    background-color: #fff;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 500px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #ddd;
}
.post_cell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.post_body {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 400px;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
.profile_img {
    border: solid 3px #ccc;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    margin: 0px 15px;
}
.post_info {
    color: #c3c3c3;
    font: normal 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
a.no_style {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: inherit;
    font: inherit;
}
p {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    color: #525254;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    line-height: 18px;
    font: normal 15px Arial, Helvetica, sans;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="post">
    <div class="post_cell">
        <input type="checkbox" />
    </div>
    <div class="post_cell">
        <img class="profile_img" src="" height="48">
    </div>
    <div class="post_body">
        <div class="post_details">
            <h2>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank" class="no_style">user</a>
            </h2>
            <span class="post_info">
                <span class="passed_time">15 hours ago</span> | 
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="no_style">3 Comments</a>
            </span>
        </div>
<p>zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can check out this for more: http://jsfiddle.net/Le4zK/16/

Comment: I would like to know too. Once I saw this thing on Facebook Comments too.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856307/wordwrap-a-very-long-string and subsequently http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320184/who-has-solved-the-long-word-breaks-my-div-problem-hint-not-stackoverflow.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Write this `word-wrap: break-word;` instead of `word-break: break-all;`

**EDIT :**

Maybe this a bug with `display:table` property. I did some changes in css:
Put `display:table` in `parent` div.

```css
.post{
    background-color: #fff;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 500px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #ddd;
    display:table;
}
```

Remove `display:table-cell` from `.post_body` css:

```css
.post_body{
    width: 580px;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Check if this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/Le4zK/30/) works for you.

Comment: Not sure why but Google Chrome has a undocumented property `word-break: break-word;`. You can see the autocomplete in action here http://goo.gl/PAktsq

Answer (score 4):

Long ago I tried to solve this problem and I couldn't find any css only cross-browser solution so I ended up inserting zero-width spaces `&#8203;` into long words using javascript:

```
var breakableLongWord = '';
for( var i = 0; i < longWord.length; i += 10 ) {
    if( i ) breakableLongWord += String.fromCharCode( 8203 );
    breakableLongWord += longWord.substr( i, 10 );
}
```

As I said it was long ago so you might be able to find a better solution with newer browser technologies.

Comment: nice solution :) but I hope that would be possible to find a html/css solution

Comment: Wasn't the OP asking for a css solution?

Answer (score 2):

The right property is `word-wrap: break-word`.

You can specify either `normal` or `break-word` value with the `word-wrap` property. `normal` means the text will extend the boundaries of the box. `break-word` means the text will wrap to next line.

`word-wrap` is supported in IE 5.5+, Firefox 3.5+, and WebKit browsers such as Chrome and Safari.

Comment: Maybe you need to set the container's width

Comment: but the `<p>` tag is block element as I know, but anyway I've tried to set `display: block;` it doesn't help. The `<p>` itself and it container too have some fixed width.

Comment: Simone is right, you need to set the width on the `<p>` element for this to work.

Comment: thanks :) I should fix the width of `<p>` I thought that I've done this :)

Answer (score 0):

In the JSFiddle here jsfiddle.net/Le4zK, your `<p>` is floated left. For starters, remove this. Also, `.post_body` has a display of `table-cell`. Remove this.  Then you will see that the `word-wrap` is respected but your `<p>` is too big at 580px.

Try and avoid using the `table-cell` layouts where possible, as from the example given it isn't particularly needed.

Comment: when I'm removing the `table-cell` for `.post_body` than `word-wrap` is working fine, but the respective div is gonna lay under the image because of his default `display: block`
and what about 580px, it's my mistake in JSFiddle, it should be something about 400px

Comment: I would remove the `table-cell` with floated containers, this will give better browser support. I'm not entirely sure why the width is ignored with `table-cell`.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4SfP2/) solution.

The problem was the `<p>` tag length. Giving it a percentage width based on the parent with position set to relative seems to fix the issue. I also wrapped the content in another div.

The trick is to contain all the long element inside a parent div, since you are altering the display properties and using floating, this will keep the content flow normal for the elements inside the divs.

Comment: thanks for your solution :) I just has to add a width to `<p>`

Answer (score -1):

I would use `overflow-x: hidden` on your parent container.

Comment: That wouldn't be the right solution, I don't want to hide a part of word

Comment: Except for some long urls, the input is probably bogus. I often do this when displaying user text in narrow regions such as sidebar widgets of my layout as a defensive approach.