# Add hyphen before word-break

Tags: html, css

Maybe this is not possible, but I was wondering if there is a way to automatically insert a hyphen to the end of a long string with no whitespace before breaking a word? This  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/76qBy/) demonstrates the issue I am having. Thank you.

```
table {
        width:200px; 
        word-wrap:break-word;
        table-layout: fixed;
      }

<table>
  <td>Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis</td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

I think your best bet would be a javascript solution.

- There is a `hyphens` property in css3, does not do exactly what you want (at least not in all browsers yet) I think, but might be interesting, you can read on it [here](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/word-break/) or
  [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/hyphens).
- Or here they discuss it a little too and mention a javascript plugin
  **hyphenator**: [wordwrap a very long string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856307/wordwrap-a-very-long-string/856322#856322)

Hope some of this helps.

Answer (score 4):

For webkit browsers this should work:

```
table 
{
   width: 200px;
   word-break: break-word;
   -webkit-hyphens: auto;
}
```

This works for me on iOS Chrome, but not OS X Chrome.  [This](http://blog.kenneth.io/blog/2012/03/04/word-wrapping-hypernation-using-css/) blog post explains the solution for other browsers, although, it still didn't work for me on OS X Chrome.

The solution shown there is:

```
table 
{
   -ms-word-break: break-all;
   word-break: break-all;

   // Non standard for webkit
   word-break: break-word;

   -webkit-hyphens: auto;
   -moz-hyphens: auto;
   hyphens: auto;
}
```

If this doesn't work in the browsers you need, check out [hyphenator](https://code.google.com/p/hyphenator/) - a javascript utility that may better accomplish what you need.

Comment: Ben, you basically wrote up the same suggestions I did. That makes it then more likely that they are correct ;-) I tested the `hyphens` in different browsers, and the results were quite inconsistent the second link that I provided in the answer also offers a compatibility table https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/hyphens#Browser_compatibility So yes ... I guess the hyphenator will be the way to go until the `hyphens` become more widely supported.

Answer (score 1):

Please see this fiddle, may be work.

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/76qBy/`
```

Comment: this is the origal jsfiddle version that I posted, I think you might have forgotten to add the update version number after '/' thanks.

Comment: I think this is the updated version http://jsfiddle.net/76qBy/2