# Put line when breaking word

Tags: html, css

How to put a "-" when the text is too small for a div box and should have a break line option.

Example:http://jsfiddle.net/2rqv6/

```
div id="box"> TExttexttexttext </div>

#box { border:1px solid #000;
   width:50px;
   height:auto;
   word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

I want the the text go on another line to put "-".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498154/add-hyphen-before-word-break

Answer (score 0):

Check out the CSS property "hyphens"

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/h/hyphenate/

```
#box { border:1px solid #000;
       width:50px;
       height:auto;
       word-wrap: break-word;
       hyphens:auto;
}
```

Note you'll have to use -webkit, -moz, etc prefixs for respective cross browser compatibility