# Percentage width inside percentage width - long words resize the table

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have this code:

```
<table id="container" style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
        <td id="col1" style="width: 50%">
            <div class="someElement"></div>
            <div class="someElement"></div>
            <div class="someElement"></div>
        </td>
        <td id="col2">
            <div class="someElement"></div>
            <div class="someElement"></div>
            <div class="someElement"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I would like someElement to have "width 95%" (of "col1" or "col2" respectively). The problem is, someElement contains large amount of text, and when there are really long words, someElement changes width of the entire table. I am using the "word-wrap: break-word" property. I know that I could give the container a fixed width but I want the container to always take 95% of width, regardless of user's screen resolution.

How do I approach this?

Comment: You aren't closing your divs. That might be one of the problems =)

Comment: Sorry, I just typed this code to give an example but in my real code the divs are being closed

Comment: `overflow: auto` and `overflow: hidden` come to my mind. Are you looking for this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Comment: possible duplicate of [wordwrap a very long string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856307/wordwrap-a-very-long-string)