# Windows style Icon and Filename in HTML using CSS

Tags: html, css

I couldn't find on the internet. If there is a link similar to my question do let me know.

I want to achieve style like windows icon and filename in HTML using CSS. Check attached image. In below case filename is long without space in it but it is showing properly.

Filename: `robot_circuits_computer_technology_desktop_1680x1050_hd-wallpaper-967920.jpg`

I tried following css property with different values and different group of property.

- text-overflow:ellipsis;
- overflow: hidden
- width: xxpx;
- white-space:nowrap;
- word-wrap:break-word;

[image]

Comment: [This question could be helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856307/wordwrap-a-very-long-string).

Answer (score 0):

CSS property `text-overflow:ellipsis` works right the text is one line only.

If you need ellipsis on the end of the multi-line text, you must use a `jQuery` plugin.

For example:

1. [jQuery ellipsis](http://plugins.jquery.com/ellipsis/)
2. [jQuery dot dot dot](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/)