# HTML - Convert String to multiple lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an big Problem that I would like to solve.

**PROBLEM**

- One line Strings that be displayed over the element width

**CODE EXAMPLE**

```css
.box {
  width:150px; 
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p>THIS IS A LONG STRING<br>
  BUT_THIS_WOULD_BE_THE_PRBLEM_WHEN_A_STRING_HAVE_NO_SPACES!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!</p>  
</div>
```

Maybe someone know how I can display the Text likes this.(Only in JS,JQuery,CSS)

**WANTED RESULT**

```css
.box {
  width: 150px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p>THIS IS A LONG STRING<br>AND_THIS_IS_THE-<br>CONVERTED_STR-<br>ING
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to break just at X number of characters or only if that character is a non alpha character? Also does `Only in JS,JQuery,CSS` mean you don't want a PHP solution (if so I'd remove the PHP tag)..

Comment: Have you tried text-wrap?

Comment: Only if that word is longer than the element and have no spaces.Thank you Theunis,that would be work

Comment: Used `word-wrap: break-word;` for your `p tag`.

Comment: Try `word-wrap: break-word;`, I think you need that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wrapping long email addresses in small boxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23776767/wrapping-long-email-addresses-in-small-boxes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should use [word-wrap](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp)

> *Allow long words to be able to break and wrap onto the next line:*

```css
.box {
  width:150px; 
  border: 2px solid black;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p>THIS IS A LONG STRING<br>
  BUT_THIS_WOULD_BE_THE_PRBLEM_WHEN_A_STRING_HAVE_NO_SPACES!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!</p>  
</div>
```