# CSS width issue on mobile responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

Wondering why the 2 pages, About and Contact have different width when it comes to the text.

They are both using the same style but one is narrow and one is wider. Mainly noticed this on the mobile version especially and its driving me crazy.

https://genesisventuresinvestments.com/about.html

https://genesisventuresinvestments.com/contact.html

```
.dummy-dummy-text{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  padding: 0 20px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

[image: This is narrow for some reason]
[image: This is wider]

Comment: I think the problem is the email address, which prevents a new line. You should modify the way you handle `white-space`.

Comment: @Benchy I have the same thought as you, the email in the `a` tag will not automatically return a line, so we need to handle word breaks for the `a` tag.
I tried using `word-wrap: break-all;` and it works.

Comment: add these property to `a` tag .  `word-wrap: anywhere;` for firefox and `word-wrap: break-word; or word-wrap: break-all; ` for chrome,

Comment: But i want it to look wide just as the email one. As opposed to the narrow version up top. @M.RMRF

Comment: look this answer ,  i hope help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23777535/10749726

Answer (score 0):

I used `word-break: break-word` and works fine, however I'd recommend using clamp() to edit the font size as a best practice, here are some suggestions

```
h1 {
font-size: clamp(1.913rem, calc( 12px + 2.475vw ), 2.587rem);
line-height: 1.1;
}


h2 {
font-size: clamp(1.575rem, calc( 12px + 1.800vw ), 2.025rem);
line-height: 1.1;
}


h3 {
font-size: clamp(1.282rem, calc( 12px + 1.350vw ), 1.688rem);
line-height: 1.1;
}


h4 {
font-size: clamp(1.125rem, calc( 12px + 0.900vw ), 1.350rem);
line-height: 1.1;
}


p {
font-size: clamp(1.035rem, calc( 12px + 0.540vw ), 1.125rem);
line-height: 1.1;
}


span {
font-size: clamp(0.900rem, calc( 12px + 0.360vw ), 1.012rem);
line-height: 1.1;
}
```

Comment: To the main or responsive part?

Comment: to the main part, [clamp()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp()) helps you make your fonts, or containers responsive without writing media queries