# Question Body Goes Out Of The Box When Showing It At Blade

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I'm working on a Forum project using Laravel 9 and for posting a new question, if I enter the text like this (without pressing Enter or adding `</br>`):

[image]

Then the body of the question will be shown like this:

[image]

And as you can see it overlaps the box that is in it and goes out which is wrong!

And this is the code for showing the body:

```
<div class="topic__text BYekan">
    <p>
        {{ $question->que_body }}
    </p>
</div>
```

So what's going wrong here?

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You need to post the relevant styling/CSS

Comment: Adding a space here and there might help wrapping the question. I wonder what the answer to this question is....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [wordwrap a very long string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856307/wordwrap-a-very-long-string)

Answer (score 0):

You need [styling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Text/Wrapping_Text), specifically

```
topic__text p {
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using one of laravel starter kit, you must be using tailwind.

Here you can find class that most suitable to your need.

- Overflow = https://tailwindcss.com/docs/overflow
- Overscroll = https://tailwindcss.com/docs/overscroll-behavior