# CSS: Set a maximum width on a table

Tags: html, css, firefox, width, css-tables

I'm generating application logs in html, and I've stumbled across a rather annoying problem. I have the following layout :

```
| Action | Result | File path           |
```

For example

```
| Copy | Success | C:\VeryVeryVeryLongF |
|      |         | ileName.txt          |
```

Columns 1 and 2 only display short labels : their contents should stay on one single line. On the other hand, column 3 may contain very long file paths, which should span multiple line if they can't fit on a single line.

To achieve this, I've used `white-space: nowrap;` on the first columns, and `white-space: normal; word-break: break-all;` on the last. Also, the table has `width:100%`.

This works great in Chrome and IE, but not in Firefox : **In short, I can't seem to find a way to tell Firefox 8.0 to not enlarge the last column of the table, and instead let the text span multiple lines**. In my previous example, Firefox prints

```
| Copy | Success | C:\VeryVeryVeryLongFileName.txt |
```

The text in the first two columns may vary, so I can't set their width manually and use `table-layout: fixed`. I've also tried setting `max-width` on the table, and wrapping it in a `div`, to no avail.

See http://jsfiddle.net/GQsFx/6/ for a real-life example =) How can I make Firefox behave like Chrome?

Comment: Also, `word-wrap: break-word` doesn't work.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258416/word-wrap-in-a-html-table , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138132/using-css-how-can-i-split-a-string-e-g-a-long-url-in-a-table-cell

Comment: Well, now that we're up to FireFox22, it looks like your jsfiddle displays fine.

Answer (score 9):

Will this work? This appears to work with the jsfiddle. Percentage based first two cols, then width auto the third, with table-layout: fixed on the table.

http://jsfiddle.net/keithwyland/uuF9k/1/

```
.actions {
  width:100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.actions tr td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 15%;
}

.actions tr td:nth-child(3) {
  white-space: normal;   
  word-break: break-all;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Right, but I don't want to set the width of the columns... And percentages don't work well with window scaling (15% of half a 800px screen is really not much). What I need is a size calculated based on the contents...

Comment: The only way I've found to avoid the table being too large was with `table {table-layout: fixed;}` or with td limiting e.g. `td { max-width: 100px; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden;}`

Answer (score 0):

use this css

```
.actions {
width:100%;
}
.actions tr td:nth-child(3) {
 width:200px;
 word-wrap:break-word;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: You're using a fixed size for the third column, which doesn't do what I need: I need the third column to be as wide as possible.

Answer (score -1):

max-width is valid CSS2 but only supported in NS7, Opera 7 and probably Mozilla. I don't believe it's supported in IE 6.

Comment: That is not what the OP asked for.

Answer (score -1):

Try putting `width: auto;`. This will tell to the browser to use the needed space...

Comment: That doesn't change anything :/

Comment: Ohh crap! I don't know why, sorry!

Answer (score -1):

this should work:

```
    .actions tr td:nth-child(3) {
         white-space: normal;
         word-break: break-all;
         max-width:200px;
     }
```

Comment: I don't want to specify a maximum width for the third column, since the webpage might be viewed on a wide range of monitors...

Answer (score -1):

The following CSS seems to get it to work for me. Note the addition of table-layout:fixed, and the use of word-wrap: break-word.

```
.actions {
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}

.actions tr td {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.actions tr td:nth-child(3) {
    white-space:normal;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: This is not optimal: all colums end up taking the same space, while the two first ones could be shrunk without breaking their content, giving more space for the last one.